# Image won't fit into the parent container

Tags: html, css

As I've been familiarizing myself with CSS, I thought I had these images under control, but apparently I don't. I have a bg image for a section and I've had to move the image around to position it correctly with the buttons and whatnot, but I've noticed that it's now widening the whole page.

So far, I've tried a bunch of solutions people on here seem to have asked for, I've tried setting a max width for the parent container, I've tried hiding the overflow, but I might be missing something. I notice with the inspector that the image is also creeping into the next section.

```css
header{
  max-width:100%;
}
#hero-bg {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549737328-8b9f3252b927?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80") center center no-repeat;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <!-- Header BG Image -->
      <div id="hero-bg"></div>
      <!-- Logo & Nav -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="nav-bar">
          <div id="logo"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt="" /></div>
          <div id="mobile-nav">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <ul id="main-nav">
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
            <li><a href="''" class="btn">LOREM</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Hero Content -->
        <div id="hero-showcase">
          <h1 class="hero-head">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <p class="hero-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
            dolore enim ab, fugit natus rerum eveniet delectus consectetur
            asperiores iusto accusantium modi recusandae. Incidunt autem iusto
            aut dolores reprehenderit corrupti vitae quae? Similique ratione
            alias aliquid nesciunt quidem quisquam porro!
          </p>
          <a href="#section1" class="info-btn btn">LOREM</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: I have added an image. can you please tell us or show us what you are expecting. thanks

Comment: Well 100% plus 60px are more than 100%, the math is rather simple … and the solution as well, see `box-sizing`.

Comment: hey @XenioGracias [here's basically what I'm looking to do and what's happening] (https://imgur.com/a/6NxRW9d).

Comment: @04FS you may be on to something here. I haven't tried box-sizing yet! I almost never use it because I don't really understand how it works,but now's probably a good time to get familiar with it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:absolute` makes your image positioned relative to it's `relative` parent. So you need to make the parent `position:relative` if you want it to be contained. And then you can add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element. (overflow only hides all its children that spill over, so there is no use using overflow for the image itself).

I've added a placeholder image to your example so you can see that the images doesn't go past the end of the container.

```css
header{
  max-width:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#hero-bg {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000") center center no-repeat;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <!-- Header BG Image -->
      <div id="hero-bg"></div>
      <!-- Logo & Nav -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="nav-bar">
          <div id="logo"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt="" /></div>
          <div id="mobile-nav">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <ul id="main-nav">
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
            <li><a href="''" class="btn">LOREM</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Hero Content -->
        <div id="hero-showcase">
          <h1 class="hero-head">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <p class="hero-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
            dolore enim ab, fugit natus rerum eveniet delectus consectetur
            asperiores iusto accusantium modi recusandae. Incidunt autem iusto
            aut dolores reprehenderit corrupti vitae quae? Similique ratione
            alias aliquid nesciunt quidem quisquam porro!
          </p>
          <a href="#section1" class="info-btn btn">LOREM</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! The Absolute/Relative positioning seems to have fixed it. Learned something new.